# Schedule laravel command to run at a user-defined time

Tags: php, curl, laravel-4, cron, command

I have a questions how to solve a certain problem in Laravel 4.

A user can plan an event to have a specified start and end time. When the start time is reached, it needs to execute a command. The command itself is just a CURL exec with some parameters.

Currently, we are firing this on the commandline with `php exec` on the OS (via cron or similar). However, this does not really achieve what we want because the start and end time can change so we need to remove this job from the OS and incorporate it in the Laravel application itself.

So what is the best approach for this?

- putting the curl exec in a queue with beanstalkd and run it once at a certain time? then delete the job when the user changes his event?
- Any other options? A cron job would be specific at 1 minute correct?

Comment: use `at`. it's basically cron for single-shot jobs.

Comment: What about removing specific jobs? is that possible as well?

Comment: I have created a work arround to be specific. Basicly we are using a 1 minute cron with a 5 sec sleep. This way we are constantly checking to do stuff at almost specific time.